# Creating private AWS API gateway using pulumi - BadRequestException: Private REST API doesn't have a resource policy attached to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, pulumi

I'm trying to use `pulumi` to deploy a private API using code similar to the following:

```
const api = new awsx.apigateway.API(
        `${this.resourcesPrefix}-private-api`,
        {
            stageName: this.config.environment,
            restApiArgs: {
                disableExecuteApiEndpoint: true,
                endpointConfiguration: {
                    types: "PRIVATE",
                    vpcEndpointIds: this.config.vpcEndpoints
                },
                minimumCompressionSize: this.config.disableCompression
                    ? -1
                    : this.config.minimumCompressionSize ?? 1024,
            },
            stageArgs: {
                xrayTracingEnabled: true,
                tags: {
                    [TagKeys.Domain]: this.config.tagDomain,
                    [TagKeys.AccessLevel]: TagAccessLevel.Public,
                },
            },
            routes,
        }
    );

    // Update the resource policy with the actual restApiId after the API Gateway is created
    api.restAPI.apply(restApi => {
        const policy = new aws.apigateway.RestApiPolicy(`${restApi.id}-ResourcePolicy`, {
        restApiId: restApi.id,
        policy: pulumi.interpolate`{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "execute-api:${restApi.id}/*/*/*",
                "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": ${JSON.stringify(this.config.vpcEndpoints)}
                }
                }
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "execute-api:${restApi.id}/*/*/*"
            }
            ]
        }`,
        });
    });
```

The code fails with `BadRequestException: Private REST API doesn't have a resource policy attached to it`. From what I understand to fix it I need to define the resource policy while creating the API. The problem being the restApi id will not be available in the `awsx.apigateway.API` constructor.

What can I do to fix this issue